# Firewalld - restrict traffic to specific IPs

Tags: firewalld

I'm trying to setup firewalld to restrict access to the CentOS7 server to specific IPs (192.168.10.5 and 167.165.100.22) both for incoming and outgoing traffic.

I have only one network interface, enp0s01.

I have switched the firewalld a custom zone that has 'ssh' service enabled.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=customlist --list-all
internal (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: enp0s01
sources:
services: ssh
ports:
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
source-ports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
```

I tested with adding one IP address, for example,

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-source=192.168.10.5
```

However, other IPs within the network could still access the server via ssh.

How can I restrict the access? I thought firewall blocks all traffic unless explicitly whitelisted by adding the source.

Comment: Your rule looks perfectly fine. Did you apply it with `firewall-cmd --reload`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Background

In researching this it appears that you cannot restrict outgoing traffic using the basic firewalld commands. Several sources back this up:

- [How To Drop Outbound Connections With Firewalld](https://cogitantium.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-drop-outbound-connections-with.html)
- [Understanding Firewalld in Multi-Zone Configurations](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/understanding-firewalld-multi-zone-configurations)
- [Firewalld OutBound rules](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3238521)

Your only recourse is to make use of `firewall-cmd --direct ...` commands which do little more than facilitate `iptables` rules for you. Given this you have a choice of doing this through Firewalld or just doing this using whatever methods you may have employed previously when using `iptables`.

**NOTE:** direct rules will look something like this:

```
$ firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 74.125.136.99/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j DROP
```

#### Potential solution

If you can relax the requirement of disallowing the host from any outgoing communications, you can get most of what you want as follows using the basic `firewall-cmd` commands.

**NOTE:** In my example I have 3 nodes:

- 192.168.56.101 - VM #1 - server with Firewalld rules
- 192.168.56.102 - VM #2
- 192.168.56.1 - my laptop

*Firwalld commands:*

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-source=192.168.56.101/32
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-source=192.168.56.1/32
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-port=8080/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --set-target=DROP
```

With this set up I can access VM #1 from my laptop, but cannot from anywhere else, such as from VM #2.

*default zone*

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public
```

*active zones*

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
internal
  sources: 192.168.56.101/32 192.168.56.1/32
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
```

*public zone's setup*

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

*internal zone's setup*

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.56.101/32 192.168.56.1/32
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client
  ports: 8080/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

*public zone's default target*

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --get-target
DROP
```

#### Testing

To test this setup, I'm going to make use of `nc` (ncat) to create a 'listener daemon' on port 8080 and use `curl -v telnet://...` commands to act as clients which will connect to these listeners.

**NOTE:** This is purely to illustrate that things are working as expected, and can be removed later on.

*On VM #1:*

```
$ nc -4 -l -p 8080 -k
```

*Now on VM #2 notice we cannot connect:*

```
$ timeout 1 curl -v telnet://192.168.56.101:8080
* About to connect() to 192.168.56.101 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.56.101...
$
```

*While on laptop we can:*

```
$ timeout 1 curl -v telnet://192.168.56.101:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://192.168.56.101:8080/
*   Trying 192.168.56.101...
* Connected to 192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101) port 8080 (#0)
$
```

The only catch with this approach, is that the VM #1 node can still egress:

```
$ timeout 2 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=26.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=25.6 ms
$

$ timeout 1 curl -v telnet://www.google.com:80
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 216.58.217.164...
* Connected to www.google.com (216.58.217.164) port 80 (#0)
$
```

#### References

- [Whitelist source IP addresses in CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/707774/how-to-create-advanced-rules-with-firewall-cmd
- [How To Drop Outbound Connections With Firewalld](https://cogitantium.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-drop-outbound-connections-with.html)
- [Firewalld Rich and Direct Rules: Setting up RHEL 7 Server as a Router](https://www.lisenet.com/2016/firewalld-rich-and-direct-rules-setup-rhel-7-server-as-a-router/)