# How can I configure firewalld to share a single interface with multiple zones?

Tags: centos, firewalld

CentOS 7

I have two zones (home and public).   I'd like to allow SSH from my home but not from public.

```
[root@foobox ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=home
home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 1.2.3.4
  services: ssh https
  ports: 12345/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

[root@foobox~]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: https
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks: echo-reply
  rich rules:
```

Since there's no interface or source associated with the public zone, I suspect that everything is matching home and using that.

I only have one interface and don't want to create a dual-homed setup... so how can I tell firewall-cmd "if the remote client is coming from 1.2.3.4 use the home zone... if it's any other remote source IP, use the public zone"?

I thought it might be as simple as just adding an interface but I get an error:

```
[root@foobox ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=eth0
Error: ZONE_CONFLICT: eth0
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Whitelist source IP addresses in CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159873/315749)