# FirewallD and docker: block a port from being publicly accessible

Tags: docker, firewalld, docker-compose

I am having some issues trying to restrict access to 2 docker containers I am currently running using Centos8 and Firewalld.
First of all, the containers have the following configuration:

```
services:
  service1:
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
  service2:
    ports:
      - 6969:6969
```

The docker zone has the following (default)configuration:

```
docker (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br-b2ef50b272a2 docker0
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
```

When leaving things like this, if I run docker-compose up, the apps are running and there is communication between them but their ports are also accessible through the public internet.
My end goal is to have intra communication between the apps, but block access to their ports from the public and only allow specific IPs.
What I have done so far and did not work:

1. First of all I tried changing the target of the docker zone to `default`
   That only broke the communication between the 2 applications, and nothing else
2. Added a rich rule:
   `rule family="ipv4" source NOT address="X.X.X.X" port port="6969" protocol="tcp" reject`
   The rule gets ignored.

Is there a way to block access to those ports using FirewallD and docker zone, while at the same the 2 services can communicate with each other?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a reverse proxy service to your setup, then stop exposing the service1 & service2 ports and let the reverse proxy filter the traffic.

If you don't expose the ports the containers can still talk to each other (in the same docker network) and resolve the IPs by service names via the built-in docker DNS. (Ex. service1, service2).

In that case your compose file would roughly look like this:

```
services:
  service1:

  service2:

  proxy:
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - <extra ports>:<extra ports>
```

For example you can use an nginx container with the extra config:
(just make sure the proxy is configured to listen on the external ports you specify under it's service.):

```
location /service1 {
    allow X.X.X.X;
    deny  all;
    proxy_pass http://service1:1234;
}

location /service2 {
    allow X.X.X.X;
    deny  all;
    proxy_pass http://service2:6969;
}
```

Alternatively you can create two "server" directives under the nginx config each listening on one of the service ports and then passing traffic via the root location ("/") if you don't want to add a path to the URL.

This will additionally allow you to run multiple copies of you services, all listening on the same ports while still being able to expose them (and filter traffic) via the reverse proxy.

Comment: Hey mate. Thank you for your reply. I understand the basics behind using a reverse Nginx proxy, but I am looking more for a solution that can be applied natively to firewalld. The newest version of Docker should have full support with it, so I guess there is a way to achieve this without using yet another container? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @machillef Ah ok, I thought you were just looking for a way to get the behavior.
Either way take a look at this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185094/502730
Seems like what you want, note that you need to "lock down" the default zone for this to work properly and just add /32 subnets as "source" if you want specific IPs and make sure the ports you're exposing form the container are not allowed in the Default zone..