# How to block all incoming connections except one country using firewalld or iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I found country IP list: https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker

I tried to drop all then add the iptables from that list but it didn't work, can I get some help?
Thanks.

Comment: See the second answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7

Comment: The ordering of the rules is important: the first rule that matches the traffic and has an ACCEPT, REJECT or DROP target will decide the fate of the packet. If you make your first rule a "drop all" rule, then the later rules cannot "un-drop" packets that have already been dropped.